# Why link_to lost 1 of 2 params in rails 3.2.12?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

There is a `view_hanlder` method in our rails 3.2.12 app. It is defined as :

```
   def view_handler
      index  = params[:index].to_i
      url = params[:url]
      msg = params[:msg]
      #redirect to the page by url  
      if msg.nil?                                                         
        redirect_to url
      else
        redirect_to url, :notice => msg
      end 
    end
```

Here is the link_to calling `view_handler` in our view:

```
<%= link_to 'Project Status', "/view_handler?index=1&url=#{misc_definitions_path(:for_which => 'project_status', :subaction => 'project_status')}" %>
```

However in `view_handler`, the `params[:url]` is:

```
params[:url] = "/misc_definitions?for_which=project_status"
```

Somehow `subaction=project_status` was lost in transit. What's the right way to construct the link in the view so that both `for_which` and `subaction` can be passed into view_handler?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using this in your view (or better yet, create a helper for part or all of this):

```
<% misc = misc_definitions_path(:for_which => 'project_status', 
                                :subaction => 'project_status')
%>
<%= link_to 'Project Status', "/view_handler?index=1&url=#{CGI::escape(misc)}" %>
```

Basically, since the `&` before `subaction` wasn't escaped, Rails interprets that as being part of the params to `view_handler` not as part of the `url` param.

By escaping the `url` param in your view, it will come across to Rails as a single param and not be broken apart.

Comment: @@EricS, what's the CGI:: for? Do we need include some library for that?

Comment: `CGI::encode` means it's the `encode` method in the `CGI` class.  You shouldn't need to include anything for this to work, you should already have that class as part of core Ruby.

Comment: Also there is no need to escape if there is one param passed in, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you had `misc_definitions_path(:for_which => 'project_status')` (without the `:subaction` param), Rails would have figured it out, though it should always be safe to escape that URL too.